# check if sonar run passed the quality gate on commandline

Tags: git, sonarqube, pre-commit-hook

I am working on creation of pre-commit hook . Before committing the code to repo it will do a sonar run and will not allow commit if  code do not pass the quality gate.

I get this link after sonar run is done
http://localhost:9000/api/ce/task?id=AVI1VL6M3afNin76yzQz

using  curl on this link i can know that sonar run was success or not but how to check if it passed the quality gate or not.
How can i find the same on command line.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61561007/5607187) 
There is a link to the CLI tool, which can be built for any platform and used in your hook if it is OK to use a 3-rd party app like cURL in hooks for you.

Answer (score 0):

Append `-Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true` to your `sonar-scanner` command line, `QUALITY GATE STATUS` will be included in the output.

```
INFO: QUALITY GATE STATUS: PASSED - View details on http://sonarqube.corey/dashboard?id=corey_project
```

or

```
ERROR: QUALITY GATE STATUS: FAILED - View details on http://sonarqube.corey/dashboard?id=corey_project
```