# How to setup Gitlab-CI to fail if unit tests and Sonarqube failed?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am setting up a `Gitlab pipeline` and I want it to fail if any of the stages below are true:

1. When there are failing unit tests `(./gradlew test)`
2. If the code doesn't pass Sonarqube Quality Gates `(./gradlew --info sonarqube)`

Comment: You can refer to my answer here. Hope it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44086452/how-to-integrate-sonar-quality-gates-with-gitlab-ci/56494794#56494794

Comment: You can refer to my answer here. Hope it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44086452/how-to-integrate-sonar-quality-gates-with-gitlab-ci/56494794#56494794

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Sonar GitLab Plugin](https://gitlab.talanlabs.com/gabriel-allaigre/sonar-gitlab-plugin) for setting custom quality gates based on the number of reported issues. The plugin works asynchronously through a dedicated GitLab account and will create an additional job with the result (pass/fail).

We use it in our Android CI pipeline and it works pretty well.

Comment: Thanks for answering.

Although with our project, we use a central Sonar server where our quality gates are set. Will the plugin also work if the Sonar is on another server?

Comment: Yes, we're hosting our SonarQube on a separate VPS. Depending on the project stack, we use different tools for GitLab CI jobs, e.g. [docker-sonar-scanner](https://github.com/mercuriete/docker-sonar-scanner) for web apps (React, Angular), [sonar-swift](https://github.com/Backelite/sonar-swift) for iOS or [SonarScanner for MSBuild](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild) for C#/.NET. You just have to point to the right URL in your project config (e.g. in `sonar.properties`).

Comment: Alright. Will try to find a tool that I can use for our Gitlab CI since we our projects are mostly in Java.