# Break Push in GitLab based on SonarQube Analysis Result

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have an application in springboot which uses gradle to build the code.

I have setup https://github.com/gabrie-allaigre/sonar-gitlab-plugin on SonarQube and have integrated gitlab CI 
to analyse code on every push/commit. What I want to achieve is to break the push/commit if the analysis fails. 
Below is my .gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: XXXXXX:oraclejdk:1.8.0_121

    before_script:
      - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle

    sonarqube_master_job:
      stage: test
      only:
        - master
        - release2.0
  script:
    - ./gradlew assemble
    - ./gradlew -x test sonarqube   -Dsonar.host.url=http://sonarqube.XXX.XXX.XXX:9000/sonarqube   -Dsonar.login=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

sonarqube_preview_feature_job:
  stage: test
  only:
    - /^feature\/*/
    - development
  script:
    - git checkout $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    - git merge  --no-commit --no-ff
    - ./gradlew assemble
    - ./gradlew -x test sonarqube -Dsonar.host.url=http://XXXX.XXXXX.com:9000/sonarqube -Dsonar.login=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview -Dsonar.gitlab.commit_sha=$CI_COMMIT_REF -Dsonar.gitlab.ref_name=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME -Dsonar.gitlab.project_id=$CI_PROJECT_ID --stacktrace
```

How do I make sure the push fails if the analysis fails? Do I need to use webhooks. Is there a sample CI file?

Comment: Did you find the answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

@jibsonline, You can refer to my answer provided in the below link.
However the script answers only how to break the build on sonar analysis and display the results.

[How to integrate Sonar Quality Gates with Gitlab-CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44086452/how-to-integrate-sonar-quality-gates-with-gitlab-ci/56494794#56494794)

Since gitlab triggers the build, once the changes were pushed, it is not advisable to set up an automated tool to revert the code changes on your behalf. Whenever a build fails, write script (dependencies) such that the code will not be deployed. Since the code is not deployed, your environment will not be effected. Also,set up an email configuration whenever build fails.